# Can't recover residual error variance parameter with linear mixed effect model

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, simulation

In an attempt to check my understanding, I've been attempting to tweak and reproduce the results of [this analysis](https://m-clark.github.io/clustered-data/mixed-models.html) (data found [here](https://m-clark.github.io/clustered-data/getting-started.html)). In this original analysis, the author fit a linear mixed effects model to a longitudinal experiment where the residual errors within participants follow an $AR(1)$ pattern.

My goal was to execute a similar analysis; I wanted simulate data from a longitudinal experiment where each participant is assigned to a treatment or control condition, and measured at 4 time points. Each subject is associated with a random intercept drawn from a $N(\mu = 0, \sigma = .5)$ distribution, and the residual errors within a subject exhibit compound symmetry:

$$\Sigma=\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & .7 & .7 & .7  \\\\
 .7 & 1 & .7 & .7  \\\\
 .7 & .7 & 1 & .7  \\\\
 .7 & .7 & .7 & 1  \\\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Below is the R code I used to simulate the data, followed by the mixed effects model I fit to try and recover the parameters of the simulated data:

```r
library(nlme)
library(MASS)
set.seed(1000)

tp = 4            # number of time points
n = 2500          # number of subjects

intercept = .2    # intercept
time_beta = .5    # time effect
treat_beta = -.5  # treatment effect

sigma = 1         # residual variance
rho = .7          # correlation between residuals across time points
int_sd = .5       # standard deviation of subject random intercept

time = rep(1:4, times = n) # vector of time points
id = rep(1:n, each = tp)   # vector of subject ID numbers
# treatment assignments
treatment = gl(n = 2, k = n/2,
               labels=c('control', 'treatment')
               )[id]
re_int = rnorm(n, sd = int_sd) # random intercepts

# create compound symmetric residual covariance matrix
Cov = diag(sigma, nrow = tp, ncol = tp)
Cov[lower.tri(Cov)] <- rho
Cov[upper.tri(Cov)] <- rho
Cov
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> [1,]  1.0  0.7  0.7  0.7
#> [2,]  0.7  1.0  0.7  0.7
#> [3,]  0.7  0.7  1.0  0.7
#> [4,]  0.7  0.7  0.7  1.0

# create residual errors
e = c(replicate(n, MASS::mvrnorm(1, mu=rep(0, tp), Sigma=Cov)))

# create observations
y = (intercept + re_int[id]) + 
    time_beta * time +
    treat_beta * (treatment=='treatment') + 
    e

d = data.frame(id, treatment, time, y)

model = nlme::lme(y ~ time + treatment,
                  random = ~ 1 | id,
                  data = d
                  )
sigma(model)
#> [1] 0.5441348
cov2cor(getVarCov(model, type = "marginal")[[1]])
#>          1        2        3        4
#> 1 1.000000 0.756712 0.756712 0.756712
#> 2 0.756712 1.000000 0.756712 0.756712
#> 3 0.756712 0.756712 1.000000 0.756712
#> 4 0.756712 0.756712 0.756712 1.000000
```

The data-level variance/covariance matrix is reasonably recovered, but the residual standard deviation is estimated to be about .5 when it's true value is 1. Inspection of the model summary (not shown) shows a corresponding *over*estimation in the variability of the subject-level random intercept.

Interestingly, the residual error standard deviation is estimated much better by the `nlme::gls()` version of the model, despite having the exact same data-level variance/covariance matrix.

```r
model2 = nlme::gls(y ~ time + treatment,
                   correlation = corCompSymm(form = ~ 1 | id),
                   data = d
                   )
sigma(model2)
#> [1] 1.103179
cov2cor(getVarCov(model2, type = "marginal"))
#> Marginal variance covariance matrix
#>         [,1]    [,2]    [,3]    [,4]
#> [1,] 1.00000 0.75671 0.75671 0.75671
#> [2,] 0.75671 1.00000 0.75671 0.75671
#> [3,] 0.75671 0.75671 1.00000 0.75671
#> [4,] 0.75671 0.75671 0.75671 1.00000
#>   Standard Deviations: 1 1 1 1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

My questions are:

1. Why is the residual error standard deviation under-estimated by the random intercepts model?
2. Is there anything I can do to obtain a more accurate estimate?
3. Why did the [original analysis](https://m-clark.github.io/clustered-data/mixed-models.html), which used data with random intercepts, random slopes, and an $AR(1)$ residual error structure not suffer from this problem?

Comment: If you provide a better initial value for $\rho$, it seems to work: `model = nlme::lme(y ~ time + treatment, random = ~ 1 | id, correlation = corCompSymm(0.9, form = ~1|id), data = d)`. Maybe it's a computational issue.

Comment: Hmm, interesting observation, that does seem to help. Perhaps I've introduced some non-identifiability into the data...